# AD FS plus local database

Tags: asp.net, sql, adfs2.0

I'm having a total brain fart on this and I feel as though my eyes are going to pop out of my head. I have a custom attribute store tied into AD FS, plus I have an SQL database tied into my MVC4 project. The attribute store AND the database both have one unique key, which is the Id of a person. I have AD FS set up to only pass claims through that are relevant to someone logging in, what I would like is for my MVC4 app to compare the unique identifier to those in the database, and grab more information about the user from the database. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a claim that uses the custom attribute store rather than AD and map this attribute to a URI e.g. http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/uniquekey. Then get this value from the claim set in your MVC application. Use this as a primary key to the DB.

You would need to run FedUtil (WIF 1.0) or the Identity and Access Tool (WIF 4.5) to enable your application as a claims-based one.